# How to bind a command on button down (wpf/mvvm)?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

By default a command bound to a button executes on button up.  Is there a way to execute bound commands on button down (i.e. while still using mvvm)?

Thanks.

Comment: you mean button down?

Comment: Yes, I meant button down.  Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Button` will fire the `Command` based on its `ClickMode` property. The default value for `ClickMode` is `Release`. Set the `ClickMode` property to `Press` to fire the `Command` on button down.